# Laravel, valdiation alpha_dash prevent dashes

Tags: php, laravel

I have validation rule:

```
$rules = ['username' => 'required|string|alpha_dash']
```

I need prevent dash in validation, allow only underscores, letters and numbers. How I can do it? Now alpha_dash allow dashes..

Comment: I've added answer for you, was it helpful? If it is then have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 6):

I would suggests to use `regex` validation to get more power to customize in future if you wish. SEE https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-regex

```
'regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/'
```

or more specifically

```
$rules = ['username' => 'required|string|regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/']
```

**Because** as per documentation `alpha_dash` supports-

> The field under validation may have alpha-numeric characters, as well
>   as **dashes** and underscores.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `regex:pattern` in your validation.

```
$rules = ['username' => 'required|string|regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9_.]+$/']
```

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the other answers, You can create custom `validation rule`

following artisan command will create a new rule in the `app\Rules\` folder.

```
php artisan make:rule AlphaNumeric
```

**AlphaNumeric**

```
class AlphaNumeric implements Rule
{
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/', $value);
    }

    public function message()
    {
       return 'your custom error message.';
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
$rules = [
    'username' => ['required', 'string', new AlphaNumeric()]
]
```

This approach can be use to create more complex and flexible validations.

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule instead of alpha_dash

```
[
    'username' => ['regex:/^[0-9a-zA-Z_\-]*$/']
]
```